# I can't close a Modal with a button and open it again from the NavigationBar

Tags: swiftui, presentmodalviewcontroller

Im trying to close a Modal from inside the Modal. The catch is, that I wanna open the Modal from a `NavigationBarItem`. Ive provided some Demo code and cases where it works and where it doesn't:

**Case 01**

```
1. Openning from NavigationBarItem
2. Closing by pressing Button in Modal
3. Openning again from Button -> WORKS
```

**Case 02**

```
1. Openning from NavigationBarItem
2. Closing by swiping down
3. Openning again from NavigationBarItem -> WORKS
```

**Case 03**

```
1. Openning from Button
2. Closing from Button
3. Openning again from NavigationBarItem -> DOESNT WORK
```

-> The Issue seems to be that when I close by pressing a button the Modal closes but is still marked as active in the background. When pressing the NavigationBarButton afterwards I get this error in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c684d1c22SheetHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x7f9a6c52b3c0>  on <UINavigationController: 0x7f9a6d85c200> which is already presenting (null)
```

here's The Code:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.showModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                ModalView()
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showModal.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Show Modal")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                    ModalView()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func dismiss() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("Save").bold()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue and I did the following:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.showModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showModal.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Show Modal")
                }
            )
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            ModalView()
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func dismiss() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("Save").bold()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Did you actually change anything? I can't seem to find a difference :D

Comment: Oh nvm I found the change but this didn't seem to fix the problem for me :/

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I will check if I can reproduce!

Comment: @nOk I moved the `sheet` outside because the modal needs to be on the outer level of UI elements as fas as I understand it. For me this solution works... have you wrapped the TestView in anything else?